# Find Difference Between Two DataFrames on Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

This seems like such an easy problem but I'm stumped. I am trying to return a new dataframe (df3) containing the difference between df1 and df2. I don't care about differences in values, just column labels/indices. I've tried `pd.columns.difference()` but to no avail. My expected output is:

```py
df1 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14
C  C  C  C  C  C  T  T  T  T  T  S  S  S
G  N  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N
K  M  I  L  R  K  M  I  L  R  K  M  I  L
C  C  L  C  C  C  T  T  T  T  T  S  S  S
G  N  D  A  E  N  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N
Y  F  V  H  Q  E  P  W  Y  F  V  H  Q  E
G  N  D  A  G  N  F  A  G  G  D  A  G  N
G  Y  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N

df2 
1  4  9
C  C  T
G  A  G
K  L  L
C  C  T
G  A  G
Y  H  Y
G  A  G
G  A  G

Expected df3: 
2  3  5  6  7  8  10 11 12 13 14
C  C  C  C  T  T  T  T  S  S  S
N  D  G  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
M  I  R  K  M  I  R  K  M  I  L
C  L  C  C  T  T  T  T  S  S  S
N  D  E  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
F  V  Q  E  P  W  F  V  H  Q  E
N  D  G  N  F  A  G  D  A  G  N
Y  D  G  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. Here are some

```
df3 = df1[[col for col in df1.columns if col not in df2.columns]]
```

or

```
df3 = df1.drop(df2.columns, axis=1)
```

However, this second method would require that all the columns of `df2` exist in `df1` as noted in the comments by @Chris.

Comment: Second way would be a bit risky if `df2` has columns that do not exist in `df1`

Answer (score 1):

Or using `pandas.DataFrame.columns.difference`:

```
df3 = df1[df1.columns.difference(df2.columns, False)]
```

Output:

```
   2  3  5  6  7  8 10 11 12 13 14
0  C  C  C  C  T  T  T  T  S  S  S
1  N  D  G  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
2  M  I  R  K  M  I  R  K  M  I  L
3  C  L  C  C  T  T  T  T  S  S  S
4  N  D  E  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
5  F  V  Q  E  P  W  F  V  H  Q  E
6  N  D  G  N  F  A  G  D  A  G  N
7  Y  D  G  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try `isin` with `columns`

```
df3 = df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.isin(df2.columns)]

Out[215]:
   2  3  5  6  7  8 10 11 12 13 14
0  C  C  C  C  T  T  T  T  S  S  S
1  N  D  G  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
2  M  I  R  K  M  I  R  K  M  I  L
3  C  L  C  C  T  T  T  T  S  S  S
4  N  D  E  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
5  F  V  Q  E  P  W  F  V  H  Q  E
6  N  D  G  N  F  A  G  D  A  G  N
7  Y  D  G  N  D  A  N  D  A  G  N
```